# Is the modulo operation an elementary function?

Tags: elementary-functions

Since mod operation can be expressed using atan and cot, can it be considered as an elementary function?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function
http://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/Mod/27/02/

Comment: I would say yes, following the Wikipedia definition. Think that the modulo is essentially the identity function, plus a piecewise constant function.

Comment: The mod operation is normally considered to be a function $\mathbb Z \to \{ 0, \ldots, n \},$ where $n$ is the divisor. Are you talking of it that way or as a [sawtooth function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave) $\mathbb R \to [0, T),$ where $T$ is the divisor (also period)?